# Dynamically create property names from key-value pairs loaded from CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load data from a csv file in Neo4j.In my file, I have key and value columns. I need to set the name of the property of the node by using the key and then I want to set the value of this key. As an example,

```
Key   | Value
______________
Name | John
Age  | 23
```

The property on the node should look like `Name: John, Age: 23`. My `SET` command is wrong but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. If you can help me, it would be great.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///properties.csv' AS line
MATCH (n {id:line.ID})
SET n[line.KEY] = line.Value
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this ["Dynamically add property blog post"](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/27/neo4j-dynamically-add-property/) helpful?

Comment: I saw this post, however in my case I don't have predefined keys. Therefore I cannot define a list of keys

Comment: @AhmetTanakol Read more carefully the link. You do not need to have a predefined list of property names for the `apoc.create.setProperty` procedure.

Comment: @stdob-- yes I should pay more attention, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Mark Needham's blog post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/27/neo4j-dynamically-add-property/), you can dynamically set property names using [`apoc.create.setProperty()`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#data-creation).

So, rather than

```
SET n[line.KEY] = line.Value
```

use

```
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, line.KEY, line.Value)
```